# How to combine two array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
array1 
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '2' (length=1)
  6 => string '3' (length=1)
  4 => string '2' (length=1)
```

and

```
array2
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '1' (length=1)
  6 => string '2' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
```

I need to combine these two into one array. If the second array's key is exist in first array keep second array's values with the key.So result will be:

```
arrayResult
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '1' (length=1)
  6 => string '2' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '2' (length=1)
```

So how to combine these two array like above example?

Comment: Click this [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Try 

 `print_r ($arr1 + $arr2)`

Comment: @F4r-20 that is the result of `var_dump()`, not actual PHP syntax.

Comment: array_merge will not override numeric keys by the latest array values

Comment: i tried array_merge but it is not working like i want. It gave me array with new keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter the [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$arrayResult = $array2 + $array1;
```

Comment: This won't override by the latest array value too

Comment: What do you mean? It keeps the values of array 2 preferably and only uses the values of array 1 when they don't exist in 2. As far as I understand that was the goal.

Comment: I just checked that with two arrays `1 => 'lol', 2 => 'cdcs'` and `1 => 'mama', 3 => 'goga'`. And the result of `$a1+$a2` was: `array(3) { [1]=> string(3) "lol" [2]=> string(4) "cdcs" [3]=> string(4) "goga" }`   The `[1]` should have `mama` value, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Hast No. Why? That's why it's `$array2 + $array1`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that $array2 needs to override $array1:

```
$array = $array2 + $array1
```